# Email sent to user with list of contacts with a checkbox field selected

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I have a custom object called "feedback". Every time a new feedback is completed where the "X" field = "Y" I want an email to be sent to me with a list of the contacts with a particular checkbox selected. These contacts must be associated with that account marked on the custom object "feedback".

Better yet, I would like an email to automatically send to the contacts where checkbox "name" is checked, but not the other contacts.

Thanks

Comment: This question's really broad. What have you done to try to achieve this requirement? What technologies within Salesforce have you looked at (Process Builder + Flow? Apex?)

Comment: I am open to different solutions. I have no real experience utilizing Apex, but after doing some research that seemed to be the route to choose. I have tried to utilize process builder, but I wasn't able to select a filtered list of contacts linked to the same account that is on my custom object. I could only send an email to the contact listed on my contact field for the custom object. This custom object is used to complete what we call a "feedback form".

Answer (score 1):

This objective can't be implemented in Process Builder alone, but it can be implemented in Process Builder with an autolaunched Flow. An Apex trigger, of course, could also achieve this.

If you pursued the Process Builder solution, your Process Builder would probably  fire an autolaunched Flow that would use a lookup element to source all of the Contacts meeting your specific criteria. Then, a loop element over the Contacts could be used to accumulate the information you want to place in an email alert in a Flow variable. Finally, you can use a [Send Email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_action_email_flow.htm) element to construct and send yourself the email alert.

You could extend and modify the same Flow to send email to users, or set off a workflow email alert to do so.

This would be a moderately complex PB + Flow setup. If you have not used those tools together before, you may way to try this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation/units/business_process_automation_combined), as well as the other modules covering Flow.